# Memcached not storing sessions

Tags: php, session, memcached

I set up memcached (on a Debian wheezy server) instead of "files" sessions handler in order to retrieve sessions from a NodeJS server. Althought everything was working well with default save handler, now sessions are not stored any more. PHP successfully connects to Memcached, but the data is not saved.
php.ini has this:

`session.save_handler = memcached
 session.save_path = "localhost:11211"`

I repeat PHP connects successfully to memcached (no timeout error)
Where does this problem come from? How to solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution, and it could save some precious time to some people, that's why I post this answer. I had installed php5-memcache (and not php5-memcached) PHP extension, so it didn't support sessions.